# Almacenar arrar en una variable

Tags: php, string, arraylist, estructuras-de-datos, session

Estimados consulta necesito almacenar en una variable todos los valores de "Producto , Cantida y Precio" de todos los indices. Me podran orienta como realizar esto o estoy mal enfocado?

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "247"
    ["Producto"]=>
    string(14) "Causa de pollo"
    ["Precio"]=>
    string(4) "7000"
    ["Cantidad"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "249"
    ["Producto"]=>
    string(14) "Trio de causas"
    ["Precio"]=>
    string(5) "10000"
    ["Cantidad"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "321"
    ["Producto"]=>
    string(14) "Ensalada Mixta"
    ["Precio"]=>
    string(4) "5000"
    ["Cantidad"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "318"
    ["Producto"]=>
    string(24) "Ensalada Mistura Limeña"
    ["Precio"]=>
    string(4) "8900"
    ["Cantidad"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "301"
    ["Producto"]=>
    string(18) "Pollo con Verduras"
    ["Precio"]=>
    string(4) "9900"
    ["Cantidad"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Puede tener mas registros.

Logro mostrar todos lo que necesito pero al momento de guarda en una variable solo me guarda el ultimo indice.

```
    $arreglo = $_SESSION['car'];
    foreach ($arreglo as $key => $fila) {
    echo "<td>" . $fila['id'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $fila['Producto'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $fila['Precio'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $fila['Cantidad'] ."</td></br>";
```

Resultado.

```
247 Causa de pollo 7000 5
249 Trio de causas 10000 2
321 Ensalada Mixta 5000 1
318 Ensalada Mistura Limeña 8900 2
301 Pollo con Verduras 9900 1
```

Comment: @BetaM por ejemplo $variable = $fila['Producto']; solo me imprime el ultimo producto pollo con verduras, lo que necesito es que ne la variable almacene todos . causa trio ..y agregar los otros valores como precio y cantidad. esto lo quiero colocar en un link para enviar por whatsapp

Comment: @BetaM no, solo pasarlos a una variable para despues enviar el link


$msg ='*PEDIDO POR LA WEB -  *  
   * '.$fila['Producto'].' | Cant:' .$fila['Cantidad']. '| $:' .$fila['Precio'];
 
echo '<a href="whatsapp://send?&text='.$msg.'"><img src="imag/whatsapp.png"></a>';

y con todo el array que puese de ejemplo solo me llega el ultimo registro

Comment: @BetaM me puedes dar alguna ejemplo como hacerlo porfavor,  no logro armar siempre llego a mostrar el ultimo indice. o estoy mal enfocado?.

Comment: @BetaM en un par de horas intentaré de nuevo creo que entiendo lo que me dices. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar cada fila de `$_SESSION['car']` en un array, simplemente tienes que:

1. Declarar tu array
2. Irlo llenando dentro del bucle que recorre a `$arreglo`
3. Usarlo o retornarlo al contexto donde lo necesites

Por ejemplo:

```
$newArray=array();
$arreglo = $_SESSION['car'];
#No es necesaria referencia a $key
foreach ($arreglo as $fila) {
    #Aquí cada $fila se irá guardando en $newArray
    #Nótese el uso de [] antes del signo de =
    $newArray[]=$fila;
}

#Usar o transportar $newArray
```

NÓTESE que esto sólo tendría sentido si quieres usar los datos después de haber cerrado la sesión o para pasarlos a otro contexto donde la sesión ya no está al alcance. Si para usarlos en este mismo contexto puedes mostrar los datos dentro del `foreach` o concatenarlos en una variable de salida.